# Elasticsearch integer range query is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have field hcc_member_id as of Integer type. I want to perform range query on this field. I tried queries given in the ES documentation, but it does not seem to work. No matter what the query is it always returns same response.

I think I am doing things in a wrong way but not able to identify the problem. Any help is good.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use POST instead of GET. Otherwise your Json will be ignored.

Furtermore you should add a "query" field to our json:
(without query you will get something like `No parser for element [range]]`)

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "hc_member_id": {
        "gte": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: exactly what i post 15 minutes ago ;)
thanks for specifing this "You should use POST instead of GET. Otherwise your Json will be ignored."

Comment: I'll delete my answer. I haven't see our answer when I start writing mine.

Comment: keep it, you explain very well why get don't work in this case

Comment: I will expect this answer as it has explanation too :) Thanks @AlainIb too

Answer (score 1):

this is a working (for me) query

//EDIT // **IT WORK ONLY IN POST NOT GET**

```
{
    "query" : {
        "range" : {
            "hcc_member_id" : {
                "gte" : 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```